# order posts by meta value on posts page

Tags: query-posts, post-meta, order

I've been reading alot about how to order posts by a `meta_value`, but I can't seem to get it to work for me.

My `meta_key` is called `date`, and it is stored as `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Here's where I've gotten to so far:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish'         
);
query_posts($args);
if (have_posts()) while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

As far as I understand, this *should* give me what I want - but doing this on the index.php page doesn't seem to change the query. The posts seem to still be ordered by `post_date` rather than my `date` meta value, which is different.

What I want to do is override or change the query on the posts and archive pages so that it will order by my meta_key. It is present on every post so there is no issue with what to do if it's not there.

Have I got the arguments right, and if so, what more do I need to do to get this working?

Any help appreciated

**Update:**

I tried using WP_Query() with these arguments and printed out the object. The `request` method of the object ordered by `menu_order ASC` and completely ignored my meta_value_num argument. So this is why the ordering doesn't work, but the rest of the query was fine. Any ideas why WP is ignoring my order args?

**Another Update**

OK, narrowing it down. The date is stored as `text` in the postmeta table, so trying to order by it and expecting MySQL to treat it like a date is a bit silly. To that end, I wrote my own query which gets what I need:

```
SELECT wp_posts.post_title,
       m.*, 
       STR_TO_DATE(m.meta_value, '%Y-%m-%d') AS m_date
FROM wp_posts  
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta m ON ( wp_posts.ID = m.post_id AND m.meta_key = 'date')
WHERE post_status='publish' AND post_type='post'
ORDER BY m_date DESC
```

Notice the `STR_TO_DATE()` call? This casts the string as a date, allowing MySQL to order by it correctly. Phew. Now to edit my loop....

Alternatively, does anyone know a hook I could use to edit the query in place as it's called? It would be alot more efficient than running two queries.

Comment: Have you tried storing the date as a unix timestamp?

Comment: nope, will give it a try if you think it will help

Comment: The date with hyphens must be the culprit. Try `meta_value` instead of `meta_value_num` cuz with those hyphens, it's a string.

Comment: @RutwickGangurde just tried, sorry but same as before. I think you're right though, it must be to do with this custom date being stored as text rather than a date. Just playing with the DB at the moment...

Comment: Yep, I bet storing the date right will solve your problem...

Comment: @RutwickGangurde yeah that would help, but the meta_value column is of type longtext - so regardless of what *format* I store the date as, MySQL will never treat it as one unless I store it in a column of type `date` or cast it in the select. what a pain lol... that'll teach me to throw custom fields around willy-nilly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out how to get what I want, but it's still not perfect.
The problem revolved around how my custom meta value was being stored - basically as a string.

I needed to tell MySQL that it was a date, so it could be used to order the posts. To this end, I used a custom query:

```
    $posts = $wpdb->get_results( 
       "SELECT wp_posts.*, 
        STR_TO_DATE(m.meta_value, '%Y-%m-%d') AS m_date 
        FROM wp_posts 
        LEFFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS m ON(wp_posts.ID=m.post_id AND m.meta_key='date')
        WHERE post_status='publish' AND post_type='post'
        ORDER BY m_date DESC"
);

if ($posts):
    global $post;
    foreach ($posts as $post):
        setup_postdata($post);
        echo get_the_title(); //finally in the right order!
    endforeach;
endif;
```

This uses the MySQL function `STR_TO_DATE()` to cast the meta value as a date, then use it to order the posts in the `ORDER BY` clause.

So this is all well and good but it would be much better if I could hook into the query *before* it's run and alter the SQL just this little bit, I could make a big saving in terms of queries. The site is a small one so it's not a massive concern, but every little helps.

If someone knows how to do that, I'd happily accept that answer instead of my own.

References:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're avoiding the unix date format?

Comment: @m0r7if3r yes, the field is filled out with a js datepicker and having a unix timestamp might be confusing to the user even if they don't need to set it by hand. however, I've tried it and it's another solution to this problem: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d77da/3

Comment: `str_to_time()` is your friend.

Comment: @m0r7if3r that is certainly another option, however it gives birth to another question - how to change the meta value (i.e running str_to_time() on it) before it's saved on wp-admin. And the effect is still the same - I'm going to require another query regardless, the only difference is that I can use `query_posts()` instead of writing the SQL myself. If you have a better way, feel free to post an answer and if it's good I'll gladly accept it over my own

Comment: You should be able to run it during your data validation and have the same number of queries as if you didn't convert it.